# Multicriteria Analysis for flood risk analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, flood

I have used a multi-criteria analysis which uses factor weighting for flood risk identification in a river basin using ArcGIS 10.1. My factors are rainfall, drainage, density, slope, and land use.

But the result of the analysis shows non-flooded area as flooded and flooded areas as not flooded. (I have a digitized basemap which shows the flooded area of that river.) What should I do to correct it and have results same as the flooded area base maps published by our countries disaster management center?

Please tell me how to have at least 90 percent accuracy of my result when compared with the base maps which show the flooded areas.

Comment: can you provide more detail regarding what software you are using for this? Is multicriteria analysis a software extension or just a technique. I'm somewhat familiar with it as a technique. It could be that one of your rasters is ranked incorrectly?

Comment: Just a note, I'd think that elevation above river and perhaps distance from river would be logical factors to include in a flood risk model.

Comment: @ jbchurchill17 im using arcgis 10.1 spatial analyst reclassify and map algibra raster calculater are the tools.